# The Equation of The Phantom Traffic Jam

Tags: proof-explanation

I am currently reading a lot of essay about traffic to help my term paper. I have came across lots of equations including the popular ones. On a site, I found an equation that is the most relevant to me but in the site there were no derivation which makes the equation meaningless for me because I have to see, understand and imply it to my own work. If anyone knows how to get the equation shown in fig, could you please state? (even the name of the equation would help a lot)

[image: here is the equation]

Answer (score 0):

I do not work in traffic modelling, but I found the article where the authors of the formula likely derived it,

https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.79.056113

I hope you find it useful, best regards.